# Proving a relation regarding polynomials

Tags: polynomials

If $m$ is a zero of
$$
p(x)=x^n+a_{n-1} x^{n-1}+\ldots+a_0,
$$
where $a_i$ may be complex, show that
$$
|m| \leq \max \left\{1,\left|a_0\right|+\left|a_1\right|+\ldots+\left|a_{n-1}\right|\right\}
$$
I am not sure where to begin on this problem. I think there is something to with symmetric functions, but I don't know what to do. Any help will be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: HINT. Take a look at $\frac{dp}{dx}$.

Comment: I am still confused, but do we proceed by plugging in m in the derivative and taking absolute value on both sides?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $m$ is a root with $|m| > 1$. Then we need to show that $|m| \le |a_0| + \dots + |a_{n-1}|$. But note that, since $m^n = -\Big( \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} a_i m^i\Big)$,

$|m|^n = \Big| \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} a_i m^i \Big|$

Now try bounding the right hand side using the triangle inequality.

In fact this is

> $|m|^n \le \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} |a_i| |m|^{i} \le |m|^{n-1} \sum_i |a_i|$

from which is quickly follows.

Comment: Can you please explain why $|m|^n =|a_{n-1} x^{n-1} + \dots + a_0|$?

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo!